# How to duplicate values inside a numpy array?

Tags: python, list, numpy

i am looking for a way to duplicate value inside a numpy array in python according how many element it has inside (Len(-)).
It looks like this:

```
a = [ [1]
      [2]
      [3]
    ]

after duplicating the values inside:

a = [ [1]
      [2]
      [3]
      [1]
      [2]
      [3]
      [1]
      [2]
      [3]
    ]
```

it is only an simple example. I need this to be done on a big data set.

Comment: Despite accepting an answer it appears that your question is incomplete.

Comment: If you choose to use `np.tile`, pay attention to the number of dimensions of your array, and the functions docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `list comprehension`. Like this,

```
import numpy as np

a =np.array( [ [1],  [2], [3],])

arr = [[list(a[i]) for i in range(len(a))] for i in range(len(a))]
print(arr)
```

If you want to in 2-d array you can also try in this way,

```
a =np.array( [ [1],[2], [3],])

arr = [[list(a[i]) for i in range(len(a))] for i in range(len(a))]
arr = sum(arr, [])
print(arr)       # [[1], [2], [3], [1], [2], [3], [1], [2], [3]]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.
I did use your code and then convert the list to an numpy array as follow:
`new_testing_images = np.asarray(tmp_testing_images, dtype=np.float32)`
now I expected to have a shape of (9, 28,28,1) but I got (3,3,28,28,1) why is that?

Comment: If you got a 5d array like that, then you clearly didn't start with a (n,1) array (as per your example).  It's hard to guess what your really started with, or what kind of expansion you required.  If this really is a numpy array, why did you accept a list comprehension solution?

Comment: second solution works fine actually. At the end I should convert the list to a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: a = np.arange(1,4).reshape(3,1)
In [2]: a
Out[2]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
In [3]: np.tile(a,(3,1))
Out[3]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

The `tile` arguments will need to be adjusted if your array has more than 2 dimensions.  Read its docs.